# Simple quadratic inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming, quadratic-forms

> Show that
>
> $${\bf x^T V x}\leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n v_{ii}x_i \right)^2$$
>
> knowing that $\bf V$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite.

It should be simple, but can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not true. Take
$$
V =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Note that no inequality in either direction can apply for all symmetric matrices $V$ and all vectors $x,$ as your displayed inequality is, on the left hand side, homogeneous degree   one in the entries of $V,$ but degree two in the entries of $V$ on the right hand side.